# How to create a close button while the original close button is to minimize?

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to have a custom close window. 
My scenario is:
The original X button function's is to minimize the window, while the custom will actually close it. My default X is like below:

```
 // add handler by double clicking on Closing event in Properties Box
 // My below X button
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

However, when i try to create the custom close button like this:

```
void closeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Close();
}
```

It will just minimize like the default. So how do i it? Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea. Giving the close button a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private bool _forceClose;

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!_forceClose) 
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
    }

    void closeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _forceClose = true;
       Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove closing event in the button click

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        this.Closing += MainWindow_Closing;

    }

    void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Closing -= MainWindow_Closing;
        this.Close();

    }
```